# How can I use an array value from a select option as a parameter in a url?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a dropdown menu populated by a results from a table in SQL.  What I want to do is take the value of whichever option gets selected and add it as a parameter in the URL so I can call it from another page.  I just can't seem to get it working.

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM lakes";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<script>";
echo "var sel = document.getElementById('lakes');";
echo "sel.onchange = function () ";
{
echo "    document.getElementById(\"abc\").href = this.value + \".html\";";
}
echo "</script>";

echo "Lakes in the Frost Centre: ";
echo "<div id=\"lakes\" name=\"lakelist\">";
echo "<select onchange = \"redirect(this.value)\" class=\"required\" data- 
val=\"true\" id=\"lakes\" name=\"lakes\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<div class=\"lake-button\">";
echo "    <a id=\"abc\" href=\"lakes/?name=\" + > View Lake </a>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: word of advice, write php inline to html. It's a nightmare to maintain echoing out every single line.

Comment: The only reason I'm doing it this way is because I have to do it as a template page, since Wordpress doesn't allow me to use php in the editor view.

Comment: There is no explicit `this` in `onchange`. If you want to access the element you have to pass `this` in as parameter. If you were to `console.log(this)` inside that function would see it is `window`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` have no errors, you should do something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM lakes";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


echo "<script>";
echo "var sel = document.getElementById('lakes');";
echo "function redirect(value) {"; //is already the selected value (this.value)
{
    echo 'document.getElementById("abc").href = "lakes/?name="+value+".html";}';
}
echo "</script>";

echo "Lakes in the Frost Centre: ";
echo '<div id="lakes" name="lakelist">';
echo '<select onchange = "redirect(this.value)" class="d" data- 
val="true" id="lakes" name="lakes">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
echo '<option value=' . $row['name'] . '>' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
}

echo "</select>";
echo '<div class="lake-button">';
echo '    <a id="abc" href="lakes/?name=" + > View Lake </a>';
echo '</div>';
```

Keep in mind that `'` is literal and the function called by onchange must be declared.

Also keep in mind that if some user select default option (Lake1 or whatever), onchange doesn't trigger any event. Then you should include some option like `<option>Select whatever..</option>` in order to trigger events of all options.